# Graphics - blending between buffers without concerning which buffer is rendered first

Tags: ios, graphics, metal

I am enabling blending using:

```
self.pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].blendingEnabled = true
self.pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactor.SourceAlpha
self.pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactor.OneMinusSourceAlpha
```

I render buffer A and than i render buffer B. Each one of them can have transparent objects. The problem is that the order of rendering matters - transparency will work only in one direction, so that if i render A first and A has transparent objects, B will not be rendered behind A.

Is it solvable?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem as old as graphics. When rendering translucent objects with a non-commutative blend function, you must draw all opaque objects first, then render transparent objects from back to front. Over the last several years, techniques such as depth peeling have been used to approximate *order-independent transparency*, but every such technique comes with tradeoffs related to rendering time, memory, and correctness.

Assuming that you don't have pathological cases where transparent objects can't be unambiguously sorted, you'll first render opaque objects in the usual way with depth write and depth test enabled, then draw transparents from back to front with depth write disabled and depth test enabled. This is pretty much the only way to get the "correct" result with alpha blending.